# Will this site retain the chiphacker name?

Tags: discussion

Ok, so we know electronics.stackexchange has been seeded with content from chiphacker.com, but will this new site also use the name?

Would anyone like to propose any other names?

Comment: More importantly, will it retain the octopus logo?  :)

Comment: @endolith - That was no ordinary octopus - That was an Electropus!

Answer (score 16):

### Short Circuit

I like this name because:

1. Retains the error code theme of sites like Stack Overflow and Server Fault.
2. Is catchy?  That's a subjective point, but I like it.
3. The initials SC aren't taken by any other site.
4. Implies a quick path to answers to electronics question
5. Is difficult to mistake for consumer electronics.

Comment: While I like the name "Short Circuit" in keeping with the tradition of similar concepts like "Stack *Overflow*" and "Server *Fault*" -- my objection is that this is the same name as a popular 80's movie, which might cause confusion.

Comment: @JYelton - Well, I was born three years after [that movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091949/) came out.  Besides, it looks like a geeky movie anyways, which I wouldn't mind the site being associated with (though that's only from reading the Wikipedia plot summary).  I doubt that people will really be confused about the situation.

Comment: Being born *after* something is no reason not to be aware of its existence. The copyright lawyers probably won't care about birthdays.

Comment: The term "short circuit" was well-known long before any movies with the name.  I think the movie is irrelevant, even from copyright and trademark perspective.

Answer (score 13):

You know what, I'm going to add my own answer here, in case I didn't make it clear enough in my question text:

I vote to keep the name **ChipHacker**.

<sub>(& the octopus)</sub>

Comment: -1 Because electronics (less and less I admit...) encompasses much more than integrated circuits...

Comment: @JYelton SMD resistors and capacitors and diodes are not integrated circuits, but they are still 'chips'.

Comment: Wow...to those with <750 rep, this question has 10 upvotes and 5 downvotes.  Hotly contested!

Comment: +1 for chiphacker. In some circles, "hacker" is still pejorative. It shouldn't be. It's a badge of honour, celebrating ingenuity and understanding. http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hacker.html

Comment: @Joby I don't like the name, "hacker" doesn't suggest novel design, let alone designing circuits outside of casual settings.

Comment: I would pronounce this "Chiffacker"

Answer (score -3):

I'll throw out a name suggestion, just to see if there's any further interest in doing so:

### ElectronFlow

Electronics and Robotics: Engineering and Design

Comment: Interesting idea.   I think it would be easier to read as two words, but that's a small detail.  I think there is further interest in name suggestions, because we're soon to get a recommendation from Robert (or another community manager) about whether or not we're including Robotics in the community.

Comment: Current in batteries and other components is a flow of ions, not electrons.  :D

Comment: @endolith That's true but the name is an attempt to be more broadly accessible. Most people, even if not familiar with circuits at all, are more familiar with the electron from its everyday use. **IonFlow** I think, most people would assume the site is about those ionizing air cleaners!

Answer (score -6):

> I think "**Electronics**" is perfect

(Then changed his mind, but answer left the same so that votes for it are still for the right thing.  If you *don't* want "electronics", then vote this answer down.)

Comment: "Electronics", IMO, places too much emphasis on discrete components and ignores issues of programming and system engineering that we want to include.  "Chip" refers to components which require electronics knowledge, and which may also require programming.  "Hacker" does lend a less formal/professional tone to the site, though.

Comment: My response was based on this post: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/merging-season/ "Electronics" is more generic and "Chiphacker" more specific.

Comment: So this is a site for questions about iPhones and TVs?

Comment: @endolith I've updated my opinion. Thanks

Comment: I changed it back so that votes still show the amount of support this name had.  You should vote up the answer you like