# 404/Error/Captcha Images

Tags: discussion, design

As we're getting closer to launch the site, I need your help with some ideas for the images on the 404/Error/Captcha pages.

I typically keep these images somewhat whimsical or clever, but fitting to the design of the theme and site topic. The final theme of this site will have a grid paper background, see the [design concept](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/448/design-for-electronics-and-robotics) post.

Here are some of the pages from other SE sites, to give you an idea.

---

[**Gaming CAPTCHA**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/captcha)
[image: Gaming site CAPTCHA]

> **Human Verification**
>
> Are you a human being?
>
> We apologize for the confusion, but we can't quite tell if you're a person or a script.
>
> Please don't take this personally.
>
> Bots and scripts can be remarkably lifelike these days!
>
> Enter the CAPTCHA displayed below, and we'll be out of your way.

---

[**GIS Error**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/error)
[image: GIS error]

> **Oops! Something Bad Happened!**
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.
>
> Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.
>
> It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional information about this error, do so at our feedback site, http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com.

---

[**WordPress 404**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/thispagedoesntexist)
[image: WordPress 404]

> **Page Not Found**
>
> We're sorry, we couldn't find the page you requested.
>
> Try searching for it
>      Browse recent questions
>      Browse popular tags
>
> If you can’t find a particular question or answer, perhaps it was removed from WordPress - Stack Exchange for reasons of moderation: off topic, abuse, spam, etcetera.
>
> It’s also possible, in some circumstances, for questions and answers to be voluntarily removed by the author.
>
> If you feel something is missing that should be here, contact us.

---

Let me know if you have any ideas. I imagine it'd be something circuitry related. Please keep in mind, I prefer to use original, or public domain images.

Comment: I couldn't remember what each of those pages was for, so I had to go find them.  I added the text and links to those pages.  It's a really long question now, but hopefully it's easier to answer.  (There's a list with a few more pages [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/list-of-unlinked-pages-on-stack-exchange-sites); none of the others have images)

Comment: @reemrevnivek appreciate the edit!

Answer (score 7):

Stuff like this?

[image] http://flic.kr/p/Pc5n
[image] http://flic.kr/p/irnLA
[image] http://flic.kr/p/74FB2v
[image] [more here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/omegatron/tags/magicsmoke/)

"Oops. Someone let out the magic smoke."

Comment: @Endolith - I assume this style image is for the error page?  I think that's a great idea.

Comment: @Endolith - The first image is [by-nc](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.0/deed.en), the second is [by-nc-sa](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.0/deed.en), the third is also by-nc (But it's yours, I assume that could be worked out-but it's probably best if it's explicit), and the fourth has no link.

Comment: @Jin - Are these licenses OK? Where and what should we look for in a license?

Comment: @nedolith, @jin, I love the "Oops. Someone let out the magic smoke idea."

Comment: The last two are mine, so they can be whatever license, but they're not particularly good, just examples of what I'm thinking of

Comment: @endolith - The second-to-last is a great looking board, but the destruction isn't as obvious as I think we'd like it to be.  The last, though, is great IMO.

Comment: I took a few more of these.  :)  I'll clean them up and put them on Flickr later.

Comment: [more here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/omegatron/tags/magicsmoke/)

Comment: +1. Horrifying, and yet beautiful. Each photo is a train wreck I can't stop looking at.

Answer (score 3):

For the 404 error: There are plenty of pictures of crazy wire-wrap messes, or breadboard projects out of control.  Here are a couple images of a bed-of-nails tester I get to work with (and it's not even that bad...)

[image: This one is my favorite for the image]

[image]

I'm not sure about a tagline.  Something along the lines of "Connection error" should work...

Comment: "unable to find the wire (thread?) you were looking for"