# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design

Hi All, as you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable [design feedback](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/448/design-for-electronics-and-robotics).

If you're still seeing the old favicons, please load the follow urls and do a hard browser refresh.

http://sstatic.net/electronics/img/favicon.ico

http://sstatic.net/electronicsmeta/img/favicon.ico

<sub>(update: I just noticed the Meta favicon is the same as the main site's. I put in a fix for it just now, will be in the next build)</sub>

Here's the bigger Apple touch version:

[image: Apple Touch]

We have also styled the site's [twitter account](http://twitter.com/#!/StackElectronix) and the [chatroom theme](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electronics-and-robotics) to reflect the new design.

If you see any CSS bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug."

Again, congrats!

Comment: I'm not a regular user of this site, so take my opinions with the appropriate grain of salt.  Things I love:  The arrows, the favorite star, the light graph paper background, the smooth font.  Most everything, actually.   The thing is I _absolutely hate_ is the "grill" header thing.  It just looks horribly ugly and tacky to me.

Comment: Thinking on it further, I think I particularly dislike how off-white and dirty the "grill" looks contrasted to the nearly pure white of the background. (I know it's not a grill, it's supposed to be some sort of circuit board, but I'll stick to the former word for now.)

Comment: Love the new design. The title looked a bit awkward to me at first, but now I'm used to it. Good job!

Comment: @Billare, the "grill" is a breadboard. Look at the small letters on the right-hand size and you'll recognize it. The buttons are IC's that have been stuck into the breadboard. I didn't realize it till just now, but I think it's a clever design feature.

Comment: @gallamine it's neat, except that the chips are all hooked up so as to short half the pins together... :)

Comment: Can we have the Apple touch version of the Meta icon?  I'm trying to use it as the icon for our Meta questions feed in Chat. I produced this monstrosity in about 30 seconds of MS Paint: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tk4B5.png and it doesn't look as good as yours does.

Comment: @KevinVermeer I can't believe I missed that! A new meta Apple touch icon will be in the next production build. meanwhile, you can use this link: http://i.imgur.com/IQmbd.png

Comment: @Jin - I don't have the app, so I'm not sure if it's missing.  It's just missing from this question, where you stated *"(update: I just noticed the Meta favicon is the same as the main site's. I put in a fix for it just now, will be in the next build)".*  Thanks, though!

Comment: @KevinVermeer yes I knew I missed the meta favicon before, but I didn't realize the apple touch icon was wrong too. thanks for point that point.

Answer (score 12):

Love it!  However, you've probably got a better monitor and better eyes than me.  The contrast throughout the site is very low, and I'd like a little more overall.  Hate to put that on you, but it needed to be said.

One area where it could be done is the vote arrows.  On other sites and the beta, the arrows are a bright, highly visible solid orange after they're clicked.  The blue vs. gray and black vs. gray is fine, but it would be much more visible if you filled the image after it was clicked.

Also, I don't see the inverter circle for the downvote like we talked about, unless those are supposed to be diodes, in which case they need horizontal bars.

[image: Arrow options]
Current - Filled for visibility - Diodes - Inverters for down - Zeners - Alternate inverters

Comment: I can fill the arrows in once clicked. expect tweaks in the near future.

Comment: I barely noticed the difference of an upvote, @Jin must want me to feel color blind :P

Comment: I have updated the arrow sprites to be filled on active. you may need to hard refresh the browser to see the changes.

Comment: @Jin - Great!  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I really like the new design! It looks neato!

Answer (score 4):

I don't like the new font either.  For a site that deals with numbers a lot, its representation of digits 1234567890 leaves something to be desired -- some of the digits are only a half-character tall, and others fall below the line.  I just left a post with a part number 68HCS08, and it's not clear at all that the 0 is a zero, and not an o.

Comment: +1! Here they are from tallest to shortest: 6812034579.  Now, without looking back, which of these is the digit and which is the letter: 0o  The code and TeX digits are much nicer: 1234567890, `1234567890`, $1234567890$ (BTW, the answer to the question was that the letter comes second)

Comment: For the sake of completeness, here are the TeX digits: \$1234567890\$

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I wasn't super impressed when I saw it at first (it doesn't pop like the old theme did), but now that I look closer at it, I see the clever use of objects + symbols from parts and schematics.  Once I figured that out, the theme makes more sense and has some cleverness to it.  Which I think demonstrates the ingenuity of this community.

**So good work. :)**

Answer (score 1):

I just love the prompt box, its really amazing, decent color and well chosen font
[image]

Its good that I dont have 125 reputation, or else I would have missed it.

Answer (score 0):

I really like it so far, maybe some more detail (or color) to the up/downvote arrows but other then that it looks great to me.

Comment: [We did that once already](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/481/new-design-launched/483#483). Or do you mean before clicking on them?

Answer (score -2):

Did the font change?  I don't like the font.

Comment: yes it changed. We picked a font that matched Latex well.

Answer (score -7):

Absolutely horrible, wastes screen estate and has no contrast at all. Huge fat logos and backgrounds and other adblock food all over. Different parts of the page no longer cleanly separated. Everything but the main text bits essentially destroyed.

The really terrible thing is, this was over all one of the cleanest and best functioning sites I've ever seen.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it is taking up any more screen estate to me. Could use a bit more contrast, but you haven't seemed to offer any suggestions. @reemrevnivek already offered one to help and @Jin will be implementing it.

Comment: Hm. Chiphacker was an every morning stop for me, now I hadn't come back since posting that answer. (Probably won't, not that anyone cares, just observing.) Suggestion, obviously: revert or otherwise come away from the nineties and to a clean design without stupid bitmaps.

Comment: I agree with you that this design lacks a bit of contrast, but if you don't deem **the content** of the site valuable enough to warrant putting up with whatever design, then oh well.