# May I ask questions about industrial power system design?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

The site title reads "Electrical Engineering", but the URL says "Electronics". I'm confused.

[IEEE](http://www.ieee.org/about/ieee_history.html) distinguishes between the types by saying

> It is designed to serve professionals involved in all aspects of the *electrical*, *electronic* and *computing* fields and related areas of science and technology that underlie modern civilization.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_engineering#Relationship_to_electrical_engineering) also comments on the distinction.

> Electronics is a subfield within the wider electrical engineering academic subject.

May I ask questions about arc flash, motor starters, and other aspects industrial power system design? Or should this site be called "Electronic Engineering"?

Comment: If someone deems it off-topic, it will be closed immediately and you will have your answer.  :/

Comment: When I went to school, the different disciplines were called *electrical engineering* and *electric power engineering*.  There are various conventions and meanings of some of the names out there, so you can't count on *electrical* definatively meaning something related to the power grid or to opamps.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you may ask questions about electronic and electrical engineering.

The site has a [tumultuous history](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/586/what-is-chiphacker/601#601) with several name changes.  I commented about the difference between electrical and electronics [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/565/announcement-site-title-change/566#566).  Do not assume that the URL or the name restrict the scope to one domain or the other.

You'll notice that our userbase is primarily focused on electronics, but your questions would be welcome.